# Service 'app' failed to build The command 'bin/bash'

Tags: docker, docker-compose, magento2

I am new in docker. I am trying to install/configure Magento2 with docker. I have some instructions from work how to install it but for me its not working. I should install with that command.

**docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d**

but when I am running this script I have error on step 28/35.

**--- Installing application runtime---**

**Installing php composer**

All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.8.5) successfully installed to:/usr/local/bin/composer
Use it: php /usr/local/bin/composer

The compose home dir is: /var/lib/composer

**Installing node.js**

The n home dir is: /var/lib/node

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current

```
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
```

0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Prerequisites for installing to '/var/lib/node' are met.
 95 39430   95 37445    0     0  36008      0  0:00:01  0:00:01 --:--:-- 36039

curl: (23) Failed writing body (2178 != 2759)

ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build: The command '/bin/bash -c -e -u -o pipefail /bin/bash -c '$BASEPATH/bootstrap.sh' > /var/log/build.log 1>&2' returned a non-zero code: 23

If anyone knows how to fix is or if there is some solutions I will be happy. Thank you very much.

Instructions that I have :

**Quick start**

Requirements are met, see above

Clone repository and cd to it

**composer.json** must be present in **/src**

You can use sample from **/shared.** just issue

**cp deploy/shared/samples/magento-composer.json src/composer.json**

**mkdir -p src/var src/generated src/pub/static src/static**

Run **docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d**

Check with **docker-compose ps** that all containers Running

Open http://localhost:3000 to check if Magento is started

Comment: please add a link to the instructions you are following.

Comment: I added the insturctions.

Comment: The bootstrap.sh script uses curl to download something, which is failing. Can you post that?